# Making an array more memory-efficient

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, memory, hashtable

I am a c++ beginner and currently i'm developing a hashtable to get used to the language (linear hashing).

To do this, i made a inner class called "Bucket".

```
class Bucket {
public:      
    Bucket* nextBucket;
    size_type currentUsedFields;
    key_type fields[BUCKET_SIZE];
(...)
}
```

Now i wonder, if i could make this more memory-efficient, since this array of key_type does allocate all the memory at once, not when it is really needed.
Is there a proper way to do this?

I think the key_type object would not be valid anymore, if i would not copy it into the array. so saving the pointer to the object is not really an option, is it?

```
key_type* add(const key_type& key)
```

I hope you can give me some hints how to do more memory-optimized programming. I'm also looking forward for further improvements.
here is my code I wrote:
https://pastebin.com/NnucGm35

Comment: Use a std::vector instead of an array?  Also, your table (assuming it's a collection of buckets), seems to be a linked list - I don't see how hashing into that is going to work.

Comment: Why are you thinking that the pointer would not be valid?

Comment: I think [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/vector/) is what you are looking for.

Comment: @NeilButterworth lookup linear hashing, it is a hashed table of linked lists ;)

Comment: @Appyx cause user creates an object, saves it into hashtable and deletes it, and he wants it still to be in the table.

Comment: @ljeabmreosn thanks for the tipp, i want (and have to) develop the table without anything of std.

Comment: From the minimal code posted here, it seems to be a linked list of arrays to me.

Comment: Best option would be to use a standard container, such as `std::vector`, that can resize itself.   If you can't use that for whatever reason, use dynamic memory allocation to manage size explicitly.   That is more error prone (e.g. possibility of allocating wrong amount, forgetting a deallocation, deallocating something twice).

Comment: But normally the user is responsible for deleting the object if he create it. The user has to decide how long he needs the object. And the most efficient way is to store references^^

Comment: @NeilButterworth full code is in the link i provided

Comment: @Appyx yes you're right, but im i able to make an array of references? if yes how?

Comment: you could replace the array with a linked list and add an entry in the add-method or cteate the array with a size of 1 and double the capacity on each insertation, if you need a larger array.

Answer (score 1):

In [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b), the way to go is an [`std::vector`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/vector/). Every time a field has to be created, you will just push back that field into the vector and you are done.

Comment: thanks for the tipp, but i want - and have to - develop the hashtable without the use of anything of std

Answer (score -3):

For studding, you may create `struct RawBucket` with same fields, but allocate it by i. e. malloc and than use [realloc](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/realloc/). It's kinda low-level memory management, but it's good experience.

Comment: It would change nothing, but the code might become less readable/reliable. (There is no difference at all between `class` and `struct`, apart from default access specifiers for members and bases, and no performance difference between `new` and `malloc()` for PODs.)

Comment: `Now i wonder, if i could make this more memory-efficient, since this array of key_type does allocate all the memory at once, not when it is really needed. Is there a proper way to do this?` I'm sorry, but question about memory usage and reducing initial bucket  size.

Comment: So how replacing `class Bucket` with `struct RawBucket` is going to help with that? And why allocating the struct with `malloc()`?

Comment: Classes is a classes and structures is a structures. If some one made them identical memory layouts than it's his problem, but I never mix them.